# async_connect hangs - Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am sending HTTPS GET messages on port 443 over a TCP socket using boost::asio to graph.facebook.com. When I do this on my home linux box async_connect goes through instantly and all is fine. However when I run this same code on my rackspace linux server (which is also Ubuntu) async_connect hangs for about 20-30 seconds each time before the connection goes through. Here is my code

```
boost::asio::io_service Server::m_ioService;
boost::asio::ssl::context Server::m_ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);

boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(m_ioService);
boost::thread_group m_threads;
m_ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

for(int z=0; z < 4; ++z)
{
   m_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &m_ioService));
}

boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver m_resolver;
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> m_sslSocket;
boost::asio::streambuf m_request;

m_sslSocket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
m_sslSocket.set_verify_callback(boost::asio::ssl::rfc2818_verification("graph.facebook.com"));

std::ostream request_stream(&m_request);
request_stream << "GET " << a_path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << "graph.facebook.com" << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("graph.facebook.com", "https");
m_resolver.async_resolve(query, boost::bind(&HandleResolve, this,  boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));

void HandleResolve(const boost::system::error_code& a_err, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator a_endpointIterator)
{
   if(!a_err)
   {
       // Attempt a connection to each endpoint in the list until we
       // successfully establish a connection.
       std::cout << "Before connect" << std::endl;
       boost::asio::async_connect(m_sslSocket.lowest_layer(), a_endpointIterator, boost::bind(&HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
   }
   else
   {
         std::cout << "Error: " << a_err.message() << "\n";
   }
}
```

I don't get an error and the connection eventually works, but the 20-30 second delay makes the application unusable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think the delay is caused by your code?

Comment: Try to run under `strace` to find out which call is blocking. I agree to Sam Miller, its more likely your code is ok.

Comment: `16:28:12 clone(child_stack=0x7f8a00e06fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f8a00e079d0, tls=0x7f8a00e07700, child_tidptr=0x7f8a00e079d0) = 6588
16:28:12 futex(0x7f8a00e06d94, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7f8a00e06d90, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1` That is what is called before the long delay.

Comment: Solved. The problem ended up being IPv6 wasn't being accepted. After a 30-60second delay it would default to IPv4 and then work.

Comment: @user1229962 make that comment an answer